# My page isn't showing the the intended UI Ina given route in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I got the image below when I try to perform a **get** request on the articles.

[image: get route UI]

[image]

[image: routes page]

Comment: Please use text instead of pictures in your question

Comment: @mechnicov I actually have both text and the images. the images are to give more clarity to what I have running on my system. so?

Comment: Actually you haven't text

Comment: Can you please add the template to the description?

Answer (score 0):

Need to create the corespondent page for the action
so in the views folder create a new one called articles then create the page for the index action
`views/articles/index.html.erb`

Comment: `views/articles/index.html.erb` -> `app/views/articles/index.html.erb`

Comment: I have that already